# Border on UIElement to mark it as selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I got orders with multiple images of the pages of them. Now I want to be able to select these pages (of which I display small thumbnails to click).

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="pageViewer" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

I manually add Image objects in my code behind to the StackPanel (with Click-listeners for changing the selected image).
Now my question is: what is the best approach for marking one of the thumbnail images in the StackPanel as selected (for example, placing a border around it)?
Is my StackPanel even a good approach for displaying them?

Comment: why not use `ListBox`?

Comment: I have the same app basically.  I use a ListBox with declared templates.  It gives you the focus rectangle and highlighting for free.  But the main advantage is the selected value can be sync'd up with a view model property.

Comment: I haven't thought of it, still used to WinForms a little, I guess. Thanks! However, I seem to lose a lot of image quality. Is there any property to it?